# Count unique values in a table with group by, with and without where condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table:

| FUND | DATE | ID | POST |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ACAT | Friday, January 1, 2021 | 10058 | 5056 |
| ACAT | Friday, January 1, 2021 | 10058 | 5056 |
| BCAT | Friday, January 1, 2021 | 32598 | 5004 |
| ACAT | Monday, February 1, 2021 | 10058 | 5056 |
| MISS | Monday, February 1, 2021 | 10058 | 5056 |
| CCAT | Monday, February 1, 2021 | 32598 | 5004 |
| DCAT | Monday, March 1, 2021 | 10058 | 5056 |
| ACAT | Monday, March 1, 2021 | 10058 | 5056 |
| MISS | Monday, March 1, 2021 | 32598 | 5004 |
| MISS | Monday, March 1, 2021 | 56678 | 7845 |
| ACAT | Monday, March 1, 2021 | 45459 | 5056 |

I need a result set in the following format:

| DATE | COUNT_UNIQUE_ID_MISS | COUNT_UNIQUE_POST_MISS | COUNT_UNIQUE_ID_ALL | COUNT_UNIQUE_POST_ALL |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Friday, January 1, 2021 | 0 | 0 | 2 | 2 |
| Monday, February 1, 2021 | 1 | 1 | 2 | 2 |
| Monday, March 1, 2021 | 2 | 2 | 4 | 3 |

What I have:

```
SELECT [DATE]
,COUNT(DISTINCT ID) AS [CUIM]
,COUNT(DISTINCT POST) AS [CUPM]
FROM [TABLE]
WHERE [FUND] = 'MISS'
GROUP BY [DATE]
```

What I don't have:
The logic to get a COUNT DISTINCT for ALL the rows (without WHERE)

What I have tried:

```
SELECT [DATE]
,COUNT(DISTINCT ID) AS [CUIM]
,COUNT(DISTINCT POST) AS [CUPM]
,(SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ID) AS X FROM [TABLE]) AS [CUIA]
,(SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ID) AS X FROM [TABLE]) AS [CUPA]
FROM [TABLE]
WHERE [FUND] = 'MISS'
GROUP BY [DATE]
```

The problem with this:
I get a count unique for the whole table, but its not grouped by date. I cannot put GROUP BY in the subqueries, as it would return multiple values -> error message.

Dummy data to work on:

```
CREATE TABLE [TABLE] (
    [FUND] varchar(255),
    [DATE] varchar(255),
    [ID] int,
    [POST] int,
);

INSERT INTO [TABLE]
VALUES ('ACAT', 'Friday, January 1, 2021', 10058, 5056),
('ACAT', 'Friday, January 1, 2021', 10058, 5056),
('BCAT', 'Friday, January 1, 2021', 32598, 5004),
('ACAT', 'Monday, February 1, 2021', 10058, 5056),
('MISS', 'Monday, February 1, 2021', 10058, 5056),
('CCAT', 'Monday, February 1, 2021', 32598, 5004),
('DCAT', 'Monday, March 1, 2021', 10058, 5056),
('ACAT', 'Monday, March 1, 2021', 10058, 5056),
('MISS', 'Monday, March 1, 2021', 32598, 5004),
('MISS', 'Monday, March 1, 2021', 56678, 7845),
('ACAT', 'Monday, March 1, 2021', 45459, 5056);

SELECT * FROM [TABLE]
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT
  [DATE]
  , COUNT(DISTINCT case when [FUND] = 'MISS' then ID end) AS COUNT_UNIQUE_ID_MISS
  , COUNT(DISTINCT case when [FUND] = 'MISS' then POST end) AS COUNT_UNIQUE_POST_MISS
  , COUNT(DISTINCT ID) as COUNT_UNIQUE_ID_ALL
  , COUNT(DISTINCT POST) as COUNT_UNIQUE_POST_ALL
FROM [TABLE]
GROUP BY [DATE]
```

Comment: I saw this "case when" on other questions as well, but I just didn't see how could I use it as I had a different logic in my head... Thank you very much, works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

It's not as compact but If you wanted to keep the `where` clause filtering you can also get the correlation you need from your existing counts by refactoring using `outer apply`

```
SELECT
    DATE,
    COUNT(DISTINCT ID) AS CUIM,
    COUNT(DISTINCT POST) AS CUPM,
    MAX(C1.CUIA) AS CUIA,
    MAX(C2.CUPA) AS CUPA
FROM TABLE T
OUTER APPLY (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ID) CUIA FROM TABLE T2 WHERE T2.DATE = T.DATE) C1
OUTER APPLY (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT POST) CUPA FROM TABLE T2 WHERE T2.DATE = T.DATE) C2
WHERE FUND = 'MISS'
GROUP BY DATE;
```